# Issue with particular AKS policy while deploying ASB initiative

Tags: azure, benchmarking, azure-policy

I am trying to set Deny policy effect for Policy:
"Kubernetes clusters should disable automounting API credentials"
when assigning Azure Security Benchmark (ASB) initiative.

ASB:[https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/InitiativeDetailBlade/id/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicySetDefinitions%2F1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8/scopes~/%5B%22%2Fsubscriptions%2F6568e31a-1543-434f-9e1d-190387fecd0a%22%5D](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/InitiativeDetailBlade/id/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicySetDefinitions%2F1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8/scopes%7E/%5B%22%2Fsubscriptions%2F6568e31a-1543-434f-9e1d-190387fecd0a%22%5D)

Policy: https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F423dd1ba-798e-40e4-9c4d-b6902674b423

While this policy has 5 parameters in the definition:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUxTH.png)

When I assign it using portal, I can only assign one parameter  in the UI.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwVQh.png)

How can I assign the ASB intiative using the portal and supply the other parameters such as the labelselectors I want to Deny?

If this is portal limitation, how can I apply Deny effect through code while assigning ASB? The only solution I have to achieve this is single policy assignment, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Product Group (PG) answer:
the initiative uses only 3 out of 5 parameters of the policy definition. The reason why you only see 3 of them in the initiative is because the initiative is set up in a way that the "namespaces" and "labelSelector" parameters use the default value stated in the policy definition. Because of this, you can only assign 3 parameters on when setting up the initiative.

The information that was provided by PG is that this is done by design because the initiative reaches the parameter capability limit.

I'm currently asking if there are any work item focused on fixing this issue to enable the 5 parameters. However, for now, the information that I have is that it's by design.